# Interrupting someone's plan

Tags: word-request

How to say when someone caused someone else's plans to reschedule for the future.

For example, if Adam bumped his car into Kyle's car and caused Kyle to miss his flight, then which word should Adam use to say sorry for the incident?

The word interrupt sounds causal but for me it sounds the plan is delayed but not affected in irreversible way. Maybe I am wrong. I would use "interrupting" if Kyle can still catch his flight after the incident. For example:

> Sorry if I interrupted your plans.

However, what if Adam knows Kyle missed his flight because of him and Kyle have to wait for tomorrow for the next flight. I would like to learn more alternatives way of saying and words for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would use **disrupted**. As in:

> I’m sorry that I disrupted your plans.

From American Heritage Dictionary via [TheFreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/disrupted), disrupted means:

> 1 To throw into confusion or disorder
>
> 2 To interrupt or impede the progress of

So it could also be used in the case where Adam did not know the level of disruption (i.e. whether Kyle would make his flight or not). I think "disrupted" is more common than "interrupted" in this kind of context.